# What is the correct way to open a SOAPUI Dump File?

Tags: soapui

I am using SOAPUI and for one of my requests I set a dump file location. This works and a file is generated there.
The issue comes when I try to open the file. I have tried saving it as `.txt`, `.pdf`, and `.png` just for good measure.

If I save it as a `.txt`, when I open it all I see is gibberish.
When I save it as `.pdf`(.png does the same thing), I get an error when I try to open it saying it's either damaged or not the correct format.

Here is my dumpfile path `C:/logfiles/log.pdf`

What do I need to do to open this file and see the contents correctly?

Comment: Donnie, have you got chance to look at the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are using `SOAP Request` type, the response would in xml format. So, you can have the file extension as `.xml` as shown below in the image.
   On the extreme right side of the image, what you see is not `gebbrish`, may be you got that feeling because of `&lt;`, `&gt;`. Those are just `<`, `>` respectively.

   - It is a valid xml.
   - Try to open it in a browser and see, you would see the data correctly.
   - Or you may open it in your favorite text editor and replace those as respectively as mentioned above, but this is just for your visibility and dont make any difference to application that consume this xml even without replacing.

[image]

2. If you are using `REST Request` type, the response can be either in `.xml` or `.json`. So, use the appropriate file extension accordingly.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This works for the simple case; What if you are using MTOM as a binary attachment in the response - what would you do in that case ?

Comment: The answer was based on the queston. Feel free to ask your question with details.